# Corona SDK Random Spawn multiple objects and keep track of each object to remove on collision

Tags: lua, coronasdk, game-engine

I am working on a small zombie game, I would like to spawn zombies randomly and keep track of them so if they collide with a bullet object then they are removed however if they collide with the hero then they attack.

I get the logic to remove them or make them attack on collision, however I am not sure how to randomly spawn multiple objects on screen and keep track of them.

I am not asking for anyone to write code for me, just need guidance on the task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is get the **display.viewableContentWidth** and **display.contentHeight** *(varies depending on your config.lua, you can view more [here](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/viewableContentHeight.html)).*

**First** set **math.randomSeed(os.time)** on the **main.lua** file **REASON** is we want to a different random everytime we open the app. you can view more [here](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/03/11/tutorial-advanced-random-numbers/).

**Second** Store the values of **display.viewableContentWidth** and **display.contentHeight** on a variable lets say x and y and create a table namely zombies and a counter

**Third** Create a function that will be called everytime you want to spawn the zombies like:

```
local x = display.contentWidth
local y = display.contentHeight
local zombies = {}
local zombieCounter = 0

showZombies = function()

    --Gives a value from 1 to x
    local xVal = math.random(x)

    --Gives a value from 1 to y
    local yVal = math.random(y)

    --spawn your zombie
    zombies[zombieCounter] = display.newImageRect ("yourZombie.png", 70,90)
    zombies[zombieCounter].x = xVal
    zombies[zombieCounter].y = yVal
    --set a tag for this zombie namely "myName"     
    zombies[zombieCounter].myName = zombieCounter
    zombieCounter = zombieCounter + 1
end
```

**fourth** on your collision function **(assuming you have all the listeners in**)

```
zombieCollision = function(event)

    --DO WHAT YOU NEED TO DO WITH YOUR ZOMBIE
    --CALL THE COLLIDED ZOMBIE
    local zombieNUmber = event.other.myName
    print("The number of the zombie is "..zombies[zombieNumber].myName)


end
```

The trick here to track the zombies is the **zombies[zombieNumber].myName** inside your collision function.

Comment: How would I make a listener for random zombies? Usually when I make a listener I already know who the listener is for, in this case I would not.

Comment: You can set a global listener for your collisions found here: https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/physics/collisionDetection/index.html#handling then add another tag let's say zombies[zombieCounter].myName2 = "zombie" to have a reference on what was collided